# python why in my json array each json element have the same value

Tags: python, json

So I have a json template and I am reading from a csv to update the some of the value of the json properties. I then put all the json in a array to write to a file. but in my file, all the json elements have the same value. 
The issue is the old values are being overwritten some how. How should I fix that?

```
def main():
    df = pd.read_csv("Daily_EXRATE.csv")
    df = df.loc[df['Field1'] == '04']
    opdb = {
      "sell_rate": 1.2676,
      "type": "currency_exchange",
      "version": "1"
    }
    opdbarray = []
    for index, rowsr in df.iterrows():
        data = {}
        data = rowsr.to_json()
        data = json.loads(data)
        opdb["sell_rate"] = data["Field11"]
        opdbarray.append(opdb)
        print(json.dumps(opdb, indent = 4 ))

    # now write output to a file
    jsonDataFile = open("ccData_1.json", "w")
    jsonDataFile.write(json.dumps(opdbarray, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
    jsonDataFile.close()
```

outputs are all the same

```
[
{
    "sell_rate": "2.1058000000",
    "type": "currency_exchange",
    "version": "1"
},
{
    "sell_rate": "2.1058000000",
    "type": "currency_exchange",
    "version": "1"
},
{
    "sell_rate": "2.1058000000",
    "type": "currency_exchange",
    "version": "1"
},
```

Comment: show a few rows of your Daily_EXRATE.csv?

Comment: Looks like sell_rate is pointing to the same field in the loop.
          `opdb["sell_rate"] = data["Field11"]`

Comment: Is there a reason why you're converting to JSON and then parsing the JSON? Why not just access the column directly from the row?

Comment: `.iterrows()` is inefficient, and less than ideal overall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're appending the same `obdb` dictionary to `apdbarray` each time through the loop, just replacing its `sell_rate` element. You need to create a new dictionary each time.

```
def main():
    df = pd.read_csv("Daily_EXRATE.csv")
    df = df.loc[df['Field1'] == '04']
    opdbarray = []
    for index, rowsr in df.iterrows():
        data = {}
        data = rowsr.to_json()
        data = json.loads(data)
        opdb = {
          "sell_rate": 1.2676,
          "type": "currency_exchange",
          "version": "1",
          "sell_rate": data["Field11"]
        }
        opdbarray.append(opdb)
        print(json.dumps(opdb, indent = 4 ))

    # now write output to a file
    jsonDataFile = open("ccData_1.json", "w")
    jsonDataFile.write(json.dumps(opdbarray, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
    jsonDataFile.close()
```

Comment: Yep, alternatively could make a copy of the dictionary so that the field is not being updated in the original dictionary: `opdb_copy = dict(opdb)`
`opdb_copy["sell_rate"] = data["Field11"]`

Comment: You could, but this seems so much more straightforward.